# Create two subplots with certain value in a column in a Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, matplotlib

I want to create two subplots with certain value in a column in a Data-frame:

- X axis is Itows which is common
- Y axis: Iono values
- On 1st Y axis , I want to plot ionocorr when sourceId =1  and on another Y axis I want to plot ionocorr  when sourceId = 2

My data looks like this:

[image]

I know the above code will only plot when sourceId=1.But I want to plot with the conditions I mentioned above.
Below is what I tried:

```
        df2 = final_df1.loc[final_df1['sourceId'] == 1.0]
        for data in df2.items():
            fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(8.27, 11.69))
            ax2 = ax0.twinx()
            ax0.plot(df2['iTOW'], df2['ionoCorr'], color="green")
            ax0.set_ylabel("Correction")
            ax0.set_xlabel("Itows")
            ax0.grid(True)
            ax0.set_title(input_file_path, wrap=True)
            ax2.set_ylabel('HPG Filter', color = 'b')
            pdf.savefig()
            plt.close()
```

Any pointers would be helpful.
Also if this is possible in a single sub-plot (instead of two ) would be also be helpful

I tried the suggestion given but it is creating 2 sub - plots. Also not sure why it is filling the plot entirely with the green/red color . Ideally it should be just a plot

with PdfPages(output_file) as pdf:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i, (source_id, color) in enumerate([(1, "green"), (2, "red")]):
   mask = final_df1["sourceId"] == source_id
   ax.plot(final_df1[mask]['iTOW'], final_df1[mask]['ionoCorr'],   color=color, label=f"Source {source_id}")



ax.set_ylabel("Correction")
ax.set_xlabel("Itows")
ax.grid(True)
ax.legend()
pdf.savefig()
plt.close()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You it is possible on two subplots or the same graph. Here are two examples, 2 subplots:

```py
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv("test1a.csv")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(8.27, 11.69))
for i, source_id in enumerate([1, 2]):
    mask = df["sourceId"] == source_id
    ax[i].plot(df[mask]['iTOW'], df[mask]['ionoCorr'], color="green")
    ax[i].set_ylabel("Correction")
    ax[i].set_xlabel("Itows")
    ax[i].set_title(f"Source {source_id}")
    ax[i].grid(True)
```

[image: 2 subplots]

And single plot:

```py
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv("test1a.csv")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i, (source_id, color) in enumerate([(1, "green"), (2, "red")]):
    mask = df["sourceId"] == source_id
    ax.plot(df[mask]['iTOW'], df[mask]['ionoCorr'], color=color, label=f"Source {source_id}")

ax.set_ylabel("Correction")
ax.set_xlabel("Itows")
ax.grid(True)
ax.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi , tried your suggestion for a single plot but I still get two different sub plots. Since I am saving to a pdf file , I m using a pdf object . Below is my code and my output files:

Comment: for i, (source_id, color) in enumerate([(1, "green"), (2, "red")]):
                mask = final_df1["sourceId"] == source_id
                fig, ax = plt.subplots()
                ax.plot(final_df1[mask]['iTOW'], final_df1[mask]['ionoCorr'], color=color, label=f"Source {source_id}")
                ax.legend()
                pdf.savefig()
                plt.close()

Comment: @Kapil Please dont't put code in comments. Please [https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77920756/edit](edit) your post and add (or replace) the code.

Comment: @Kapil I just tested saving to a pdf as described in your edit, using `from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPage` and was able to save a single figure to `pdf`. the `pdf.savefig()` function optionally takes a figure as an argument, so I would suggest using it as `pdf.savefig(fig)` to be explicit.